# Dwolla transaction ids relationship

Tags: webhooks, dwolla

I just had a transaction that completed. The transaction Id was reported through the webhook as a an integer XXXX132. When I look at the Dwolla site of the recipient, on the receiving side the id is XXXX131 and the .25c fee has the id XXXX130.

Can I assert that for any transaction the ids are numeric and the relationships are:

Fee id: N
Receivers's id: N + 1
Sender's id: N + 2

If not, how do I determine all the ids since the web hook only reports one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. We create transactions in the following order: Dwolla fee if necessary, facilitator fee if necessary, receiver, sender. Be careful assuming SenderId - 2 is the Dwolla fee because for transactions <= 10 it will be some random transaction, not the fee for your transaction.

This is subject to change at any time so I wouldn't make crucial decisions based on this information.

Comment: OK... So what do you suggest I do to find the other transaction ids? Have you considered extending the webhook dictionary to contain all of them?

Comment: I'll get a ticket entered to include all transaction ids.

Comment: The ticket should just read "return the correct transaction id for inbound payments" The correct transaction id is the one that is accessible to whoever is receiving the webhook.  So when sending money, the webhook currently returns the correct ID, but when receiving money, it returns the incorrect ID. It should return the ID of the receiving tx when posting to the receiver and the sending tx when posting to the sender.